# how to point to a number that correspond value of this number is selected by user?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Suppose i have two table as `person` and `OfficeAccess`. In `person` i'll save the staffs of office and in `OfficeAccess` i save access of this staffs to office's building. "person" has this field: "IdKnown, name, family, phone, `IdAccess` and `OfficeAccess` has this field: `IdAccess`, `AccessDeccription`. `IdAccess` foreign key in `person` have a reference to `OfficeAccess` and `IdAccess` column. Suppose i make a windows in WPF to add a new staff and in this window i put `TextBox`for name and family and phone and i put a `ComboBox` to add `IdAccess`. but combo bind to `OfficeAccess` and `AccessDeccription` values are shown in this combo. Now, how can i add `IdAccess` to `person` when user select a value of combo? I have already said that i use of EF6.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FaceDBEntities.FaceDBEntities FaceDB = new FaceDBEntities.FaceDBEntities();

    try
    {      
        tblOfficeAccess OffAcs = new tblOfficeAccess();
        tblperson PerTbl = new tblperson()
        {
            Name = txtName.Text.ToString(),
            Family = txtFamily.Text.ToString(),
            Phone = txtPhone.Text.ToString(),
            IdAccess=OffAcs.IdAccess (????)
        };

        FaceDB.tblperson.Add(PerTbl);
        FaceDB.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Comment: Please can you include some code that you have already tried, in your answer? For more information on how to ask a good SO question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could you cast this in code? it would be easier to read. especially the parts after "Suppose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 IdAccess = from x in OffAcs where 
            x.AccessDeccription == Combobox.SelectedText 
            select x.IdAccess;
```

or this:

```
IdAccess = OffAcs.First(x=>x.AccessDeccription == Combobox.SelectedText).IdAccess;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i add "Find" method to my project in C#?

Comment: @Saeid my mistake I did not pay enough attention. I edited my answer. It might also help if you could post the code for  `tblOfficeAccess `

Comment: hey guy, excellent. i get idea from your comment and now it work. I'll edit your answer with right syntax and exact answer.